# Pipe in Makefile

Tags: sed, makefile

The following sed works perfectly in basho:

```
pkexec /opt/texbin/tlmgr install $(cat source/*.md | sed -n 's~^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$~\1~p' | paste -sd ' ' -)
```

However when I add it to a make target:

```
$(shell pkexec /opt/texbin/tlmgr install $(cat source/*.md | sed -n 's~^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$~\1~p' | paste -sd ' ' -))
```

I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

- How is the proper way of using sed in a Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is actually side effect of how make expands `$` variable references and function calls.  There are two problems with your example:

- You write `$(cat …)`, but make will expand this (to nothing), similar to how it expands `($shell …)`.  You need to write `$$(cat …)`, so that the dollar sign is passed down to the shell.
- The `)` in the regular expression is treated as a terminator for the make function call (`cat` as it is written, but it could be `shell`).

To fix the second issue, put the regular expression into a make variable, doubling the `$`:

```
regexp = s~^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$$~\1~p
```

Reference it from the sed command:

```
$(shell pkexec /opt/texbin/tlmgr install $$(cat source/*.md | sed -n '$(regexp)' | paste -sd ' ' -))
```

Now the `)` is hidden from the make function call parser and no longer confuses it.  The `'…'` is still necessary to prevent shell expansion of the regular expression.